# ConTeXt: Having problems between a heading and the following text

Tags: context, typography

The text in the screenshot describes my problem on page 1, and there is a different problem on page 2. Page 3 shows the 'right' way to insert a page reference. But I don't want to do it like this - I want to use `\pagereference`s. I tried throwing in a few `\dontleavehmode`s but it didn't help.

Please explain what I'm doing wrong on page 1 and on page 2.

[image]

```
\showframe
\setuppapersize[A6][A5,landscape] \setuparranging[2SIDE]

\starttext

\startsection [title=First section heading]
\pagereference[pageref1]
There is a small gap between the left side  of the frame and the start of this sentence. It should not be there.

\page
\startsection [title=Second section heading]
\pagereference[pageref2]

The whitespace between the section heading and the start of this text is bigger than on page 1.
\stopsection

\page
\startsection [title=Third section heading, reference=pageref3]

This has no problems, but I don't want to specify the reference this way. 
\stopsection

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page 1, there is a single blank line after the `\pagereference` that is typeset as a single space. On page 2, the two blank lines are typeset as a `\par`, that is, a new paragraph.

To fix this, we can define a new `\pagereference` that ignores and spaces/new lines after it:

```tex
\showframe
\setuppapersize[A6][A5,landscape] \setuparranging[2SIDE]

\protected\def\newpagereference[#1]{\pagereference[#1]\futureexpandisap\relax\relax\relax}

\starttext

\startsection [title=First section heading]
\newpagereference[pageref1]
There is a small gap between the left side  of the frame and the start of this sentence. It should not be there.

\page
\startsection [title=Second section heading]
\newpagereference[pageref2]

The whitespace between the section heading and the start of this text is bigger than on page 1.
\stopsection

\page
\startsection [title=Third section heading, reference=pageref3]

This has no problems, but I don't want to specify the reference this way.
\stopsection

\stoptext
```

[image]

This uses one of the new LuaMetaTeX primitives `\futureexpandisap` which **expand**s the following characters and **i**gnores **s**paces **a**nd **p**aragraphs.

Comment: Thanks for telling me what I was doing wrong. And for the fix.